# Serenity in InteliJ - test passed but browser webpage not running visible

Tags: intellij-idea, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am new to use serenity.

I setup IntelliJ - gradle project and run the serenity test on one of the feature file.
I saw Test result passed in IntelliJ but i did not see the browser launched and website auto navigated per test script.

Is there something wrong or I missed to setup?
I want to see the browser launched the steps run on the webpage during test execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup project from sample project https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter, then you can change the setting from file `src/test/resources/serenity.conf`

```
headless.mode = false
```

Comment: oh thanks! i totally missed look this line. yes setting it to true works.